# `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` on MacOS running gcc on a C script

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, linker

I'm trying to compile code from the book "C in a Nutshell". It's a C script and seems to be a linker problem when looking at similar question. And when I'm compiling it with gcc with the command `gcc selectionSort_ptr.c` I get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_swapf", referenced from:
      _selection_sortf in selectionSort_ptr_own-0c6ce3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the script:

```
inline void swapf( float *p1, float *p2 )
{
   float tmp = *p1; *p1 = *p2; *p2 = tmp;      // Swap *p1 and *p2.
}

// The function selection_sortf() uses the selection-sort
// algorithm to sort an array of float elements.
// Arguments: An array of float, and its length.

void selection_sortf( float a[], int n )       // Sort an array a of
{                                              // n float elements.
   if ( n <= 1 ) return;               // Nothing to sort.

   register float *last = a + n-1,     // A pointer to the last element.
                  *p,                  // A pointer to a selected element.
                  *minPtr;             // A pointer to the current minimum.

   for ( ; a < last; ++a )             // Walk pointer a through the array.
   {
      minPtr = a;                      // Find the smallest element
      for ( p = a+1; p <= last; ++p )  // between a and the last element.
         if ( *p < *minPtr )
           minPtr = p;
      swapf( a, minPtr );              // Swap the smallest element
   }                                   // with the element at a.
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   float fArr[] = { 2.2F , 0.0F, -1.1F, 3.3F, -4.4F };
   int n = sizeof(fArr)/sizeof(*fArr);

   selection_sortf( fArr, n);

   for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
      printf("%8.2f", fArr[i]);
   putchar('\n');    
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't really tell if that is a language feature or compiler glitch but you must make the inline function `static`.

Comment: many thanks @Gerhardh. Could you tell me which line exactly should be changed and how?

Comment: `static inline void swapf( float *p1, float *p2 )`.

Comment: Many thanks @Gerhardh. That workded! Could give some insight into the why the inline function must be made `static` (that I would be happy to accept as an answer)

Comment: As I wrote in fist comment, I am currently not aware if that is supported by the language or just some implementation detail of the compiler. Therefore I cannot answer. I would say that if the compiler "thinks" a symbol for a function should be exported, it should also provide that function. Otherwise if the function is omited because it is only used inline, then no external symbol should be created that might confuse the linker. But that is nothing to put into an answer.

Comment: Ok many thanks anyway @Gerhardh as that solved the problem!